# Lenovo G50-30 mic built in volume problem

Tags: skype, lenovo, microphone

my built in mic (the laptop is a lenovo g50-30) is too low and a bit distorted. I've tried it on skype and even in the audio settings the orange bars are pretty low. The mic is pre-amplificated above 100%. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: news here. I've tried a recording session with "arecord -D hw:0,0 -vv -f cd ~/test.wav" and it worked :D. So it seems that the problem is a skype problem?!?! Btw the optione "allow to skype to auto-adjust volume" is disabled.
Update 2: i've tried the mic on my headphones. Skype works. I'm a bit confused now...

UPDATE 2: The solution is here: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=183740

Comment: No answer but I would just to confirm the "bug". Exactly the same situation on Lenovo G50-70 with Arch Linux.

Answer (score 2):

If the microphone is a stereo one, the signals from both channels cancle each other out and become close to a null value. If you disballance both channels slightly, you may get it to work properly.

Comment: Wow, great, this solved my problem. I was struggling with it for a week.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Lenovo G50-45, sound on skype and any other recordings was very distorted and gave lots of background noise to an unbearable level. It took me ages to work out that the microphone volume and microphone boost were pre-set to full. Just had to go  into the microphone properties in the device settings and lower it to an acceptable level.